# Up and Right arrows on Mac adds an extra comma and dot

Tags: macos, keyboard, arrow-keys

I'm using MacBook Pro late 2011 with Yosemite 10.10.2

Today, all of the sudden, the right arrow adds a comma most of the times when I press it and the up arrow adds a dot most of the times.

Things I tried:

1. Reset PRAM settings
2. Use guest account and tested in Safari
3. Closed all programs that I could
4. I opened in safe mode
5. I disabled all the Shortcuts in: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts
6. I changed the input sources language from US to British
7. I searched all the internet for similar issues

Video of how it happens https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0M1vYLmv4I

Javascript event catcher produces:

```
keydown  keyCode=188       which=188       charCode=0        
keypress keyCode=44  (,)   which=44  (,)   charCode=44  (,)  
keyup    keyCode=188       which=188       charCode=0        
keyup    keyCode=39  (')   which=39  (')   charCode=0
```

I'm out of ideas, any help please?

Comment: For future reference, StackOverflow is for programming questions.  This sort of question belongs on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry for that. Should I remove the question and make a new one on SuperUser now?

Comment: nah.  i flagged it to be moved.  Eventually, an admin will come along and move it for you.  maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure there's nothing in there that is accidentally triggering the other key.  Failing that...

Either your keyboard is starting to die, or something is getting screwy with your motherboard (I think).  I've had a very similar problem happen to my late 2009 MBP.  For me, I was getting random ~! in the terminal without doing anything, and the entire right half of the keyboard got mapped to the mute key.  We replaced the keyboard, but the mute key still triggers on its own every now and then.  This tells me there's another issue somewhere, but I never found a proper solution for it.

I'd replace your keyboard (good luck! Mine had something like 70 screws just to remove it), and see if that helps.

Comment: I hoped it wouldn't come to this. I will try an external keyboard, see if that helps. Thanks

Comment: I'm using an external keyboard and it's working correctly now. So the issue is the built in keyboard. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: UPDATE: New keys started acting up each new day (ex: "=" key aded a "b" before or after, the the "[" added an "h" the same way). I bought and installed a new keyboard and it works fine now.